# What am I doing wrong? Unable to execute a line of code. Python | Data Science | Big Mart Sales Data set

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-science

I have been trying to learn to analyze Big Mart Sales Data Set. There are some **NaN** values in **Item_Weight** column. So I wanted to update my those values by finding values from a **pivot_table** that contains **Item_Identifier as Index and Item_Weight**. This is the image

[image]

```
cdata['Item_Weight'] = cdata[['Item_Weight','Item_Identifier']].apply(lambda x: item_avg_weight.loc[x[1],'Item_Weight'] if pd.isnull(x[0]) else x[1]).astype(float)
```

But when I run the above line of code, I get an error

I am unable to get why I am getting this error.

Link to data set : https://www.kaggle.com/brijbhushannanda1979/bigmart-sales-data/data

**EDIT 1**

Error log

```py
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-158-7ecf8cf7385f> in <module>
----> 1 cdata['Item_Weight'] = cdata[['Item_Weight','Item_Identifier']].apply(lambda x: item_avg_weight.loc[x[1],'Item_Weight'] if pd.isnull(x[0]) else x[1]).astype(float)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, **kwargs)
   5689             # else, only a single dtype is given
   5690             new_data = self._data.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors,
-> 5691                                          **kwargs)
   5692             return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self)
   5693 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in astype(self, dtype, **kwargs)
    529 
    530     def astype(self, dtype, **kwargs):
--> 531         return self.apply('astype', dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
    532 
    533     def convert(self, **kwargs):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in apply(self, f, axes, filter, do_integrity_check, consolidate, **kwargs)
    393                                             copy=align_copy)
    394 
--> 395             applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
    396             result_blocks = _extend_blocks(applied, result_blocks)
    397 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, values, **kwargs)
    532     def astype(self, dtype, copy=False, errors='raise', values=None, **kwargs):
    533         return self._astype(dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors, values=values,
--> 534                             **kwargs)
    535 
    536     def _astype(self, dtype, copy=False, errors='raise', values=None,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py in _astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, values, **kwargs)
    631 
    632                     # _astype_nansafe works fine with 1-d only
--> 633                     values = astype_nansafe(values.ravel(), dtype, copy=True)
    634 
    635                 # TODO(extension)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy, skipna)
    700     if copy or is_object_dtype(arr) or is_object_dtype(dtype):
    701         # Explicit copy, or required since NumPy can't view from / to object.
--> 702         return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
    703 
    704     return arr.view(dtype)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'DRC01'
```

**What I require?**

I want to update the **cdata DataFrame**, so that **Item_Weight** column does not have any NaN values. I want to do this with the help of a pivot table namely **item_avg_weight** which contains Item Weight by **Item_Identifier**

**EDIT 2**

Information about dataframe

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 14204 entries, 0 to 14203
Data columns (total 13 columns):
Item_Fat_Content             14204 non-null object
Item_Identifier              14204 non-null object
Item_MRP                     14204 non-null float64
Item_Outlet_Sales            8523 non-null float64
Item_Type                    14204 non-null object
Item_Visibility              14204 non-null float64
Item_Weight                  11765 non-null float64
Outlet_Establishment_Year    14204 non-null int64
Outlet_Identifier            14204 non-null object
Outlet_Location_Type         14204 non-null object
Outlet_Size                  10188 non-null object
Outlet_Type                  14204 non-null object
source                       14204 non-null object
dtypes: float64(4), int64(1), object(8)
memory usage: 1.4+ MB
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code in text. Also, based on the stacktrace in the image, seems like you're converting a string to float. The trace is clear about this. What further help are you looking for?

Comment: Thankyou very very much for offering your help @TrentonMcKinney.
But I just tried to run the suggested solution, and I am sorry I was not able to get the desired results by your code. I think I was unable to explain my problem clearly.

Comment: It seems you have modified the data in an unexpected way. The link points to two files `Test` and `Train`. `df.info()` posted above, contains 14204 rows. Have you combined Test and Train into one dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

- My understanding is, for `Item_Weight`, you want to [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas-dataframe-fillna), based upon the `mean` of each group in `Item_Identifier`
- This can be accomplished using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) as follows
- There should be two files, so create a dataframe for each file
- The `NaN` values can be filled, or dropped like `df_test.dropna(inplace=True)`

```py
import pandas as pd

# create two dataframes
df_test = pd.read_csv('datasets_9961_14084_Test.csv')
df_train = pd.read_csv('datasets_9961_14084_Train.csv')

# fill the NaN values in Item_Weight with the mean of their repective Item_Identifier group
df_test.Item_Weight = df_test.groupby('Item_Identifier')['Item_Weight'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
df_train.Item_Weight = df_train.groupby('Item_Identifier')['Item_Weight'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```